# How to highlight web urls in EditText?

Tags: android

I need to highlight all web urls in EditText as I type. In TextViews I can do that by using the "TextView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL)" method. However, when applied to EditText, no links are highlighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` and call `Linkify.addLinks` Here's an example:

```
    yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Linkify.addLinks((Spannable) s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // Nothing to do
        }

    });
```

You can call it in `TextWatcher.onTextChanged` or `TextWatcher.afterTextChanged`.

Comment: Yep, did just that. Thank you